# Second click on checkbox won`t show ImageView

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview

I have a weird problem. When i click the first time on the checkbox it works, but when i uncheck and check again, the image won`t show.
Please help.

```
private void ratedialog() {

        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate it!");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        seekbar = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_seekbar);
        button_done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        seekbar_result = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_result);
        checkBox_seen = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_seen);

        button_done.setOnClickListener(EditActivity.this);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(EditActivity.this);
        checkBox_seen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(EditActivity.this);


        seekbar.setProgress(rate);

    }
```

Listener:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.e(TAG, isChecked+"");
        if (isChecked) {
            //seen = true;
            checkBox_seen.setChecked(true);
            Log.e(TAG, "Second time " + isChecked + "");

            image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);

        } else {
           // seen = false;
            checkBox_seen.setChecked(false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Third time" + isChecked + "");

            image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
if (isChecked) {
        //seen = true;
        checkBox_seen.setChecked(true);
        Log.e(TAG, "Second time " + isChecked + "");
        image_seen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);

    } else {
       // seen = false;
        checkBox_seen.setChecked(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "Third time" + isChecked + "");

        image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

In Else condition you change the visiblity to INVISIBLE so it become invisible when your if condition runs you do not change the Visiblity to visible so that's why you image not shows.

Comment: @Yozh If you are satisfied with my answer kindly tik that answer Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not changing the visibility in checked state setting the `CheckBox`instance checked again.

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.e(TAG, isChecked+"");
        if (isChecked) {
            //seen = true;
            **checkBox_seen.setChecked(true);// remove this line**
            Log.e(TAG, "Second time " + isChecked + "");
            **image_seen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Add this line**
            image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);//Move this line to `ratedialog()`method.

        } else {
           // seen = false;
            **checkBox_seen.setChecked(false);//Remove this line**
            Log.e(TAG, "Third time" + isChecked + "");

            image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

The simple code will look like

```
if (isChecked) {
        image_seen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```